# finding the minumum of longest distances

Tags: c

the program is for finding minimum of longest distances for N points in a grid choosing one of the point a hub. if a person wants to go from one point to the other point, he has to pass through the hub point. The program got complied but it is not scanning the input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <math.h>
int abs1(int,int);
int dist(int,int,int,int); 
main()
{

    int x[200],y[2000],m,min,max1,max2,i,j,n,d[1000][1000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("\n%d",&x[i]);
        scanf("%d",&y[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
                continue;
            d[i][j]=dist(x[i],x[j],y[i],y[j]);
        }
    }
    min=10000;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        max1=0;
        max2=0;
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
                continue;
            if(d[i][j]>max1)
                max1=d[i][j];
            else if(d[i][j]>max2)
                max2=d[i][j];
        }
        m=max1+max2;
        if(m<min)
            min=m;
    }
    printf("\n%d",min);
    getch();
}
int abs1(int p,int q)
{
    if((p-q)<0)
        return (q-p);
    else
        return (p-q);
}
int dist(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2)
{
    int e;
    e=abs1(x1,x2)+abs1(y1,y2);
    return(e);
}
```

Comment: Delete `scanf("\n");`

Comment: Related : [Large 2D array gives segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851122/large-2d-array-gives-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0):

you are defining two large array i.e. 'd[1000][1000]' Reduce the size and your error will be gone.for reference you can also visit

```
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/314070/2d-arrays-problem
```

and

```
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/c-array-size-limit-282519/
```