# ifstream::getline segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, fstream, ifstream

I'm having a strange problem. I run into a segmentation fault at first iteration when I try to execute the following code:

```
const int lineTot = FinCurrentPopulation - DebutCurrentPopulation;
const int lseq = NumLoci + 2;
char seq[lineTot][lseq];
for(int line = 0; line < lineTot; line++) {
    int chromosome = (line - DebutCurrentPopulation) % 2 + 1;
    if(chromosome == 1)
        id++;

    if(in.good()) {
        in.ignore(8, '\t');
        in.ignore(8, '\t');
        in.getline(seq[line], lseq);
    }
}
in.close();
```

in is of type ifstream and was opened successfully earlier in the program. What puzzles me is that the code works as expected when I give a char[] to in.getline(). Also, gdb tells me that the fault is caused at if(in.good()). Any idea?

Thanks.

Edit: Made lineTot and lseq compile-time constant.

Comment: This is not valid C++. Array sizes must be compile-time constant expressions in C++.

Comment: So if I set the size of seq with actual numbers like 10000 and 10002, it should work?

Comment: No, I didn't say that those were the *only* problems with your code. I'm was just saying that your code wasn't even valid C++, so it's "not even buggy".

Comment: Then, stop using `in.good` since it have passed the good point of the stream before

Comment: Ok. But can you tell me why I get into trouble when I try to access an element of seq? I really don't see what I'm doing wrong. Sorry if the question seems stupid, I'm still learning C++.

Comment: `if (in.ignore(8, '\t') && in.ignore(8, '\t') && in.getline(seq[line], lseq))`

Comment: Ok I got it, i was overflowing the stack. I was trying to allocate space for a 1000 x 10000 char array. This post helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851122/large-2d-array-gives-segmentation-fault